# Flipped Point Spread Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab, inverse-problems, deconvolution

I was reading on wikipedia about the Lucy-Richardson algorithm and its equivalent iterative function:

$$
u^{(t+1)}=u^{(t)}\cdot \Big(\frac{d}{u^{(t)}\otimes p}\otimes \hat{p}\Big)
$$

where d is the observed pixel, $u^{(t)}$ is the current iteration, $u^{(t+1)}$ is the successive iteration, p is the point spread function, and $\hat{p}$ is the flipped point spread function.

I understand, at least in an algorithmic sense, what everything is except the the flipped point spread function. Wikipedia explained it as this:

$$
\hat{p}=p_{(i-n)(j-m)}, 0\leq n, m\leq i, j
$$

Again, all well and good, assuming one knows what m, n, i, and j are. In this context, i and j are the xy-coordinate of the pixel u. However, my trouble lies with m and n: what range are they on? Is any value fine as long as it's greater than 0, or less than i, respectively; or is there some relation to j or i?

Anyway, if someone could explain in general what flipping the point spread function does, and what these new variables actually mean in relation to the old ones, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Pretty sure the second and third commas are not separating inequalities, but rather variables that can fit in that slot in the inequality. So $0 \leq n \leq i$ and $0 \leq m \leq j$.

Comment: I see. That was really confusing actually. Thanks

Comment: It means you should use correlation instead of convolution.

Comment: So "flipped" is literally horizontally and vertically inverted (i.e. central-point inversion)?

Answer (score 2):

Convolution with Flipped Kernel is basically Correlation.

In MATLAB the function `imfilter()` has the Correlation mode of operation.
Otherwise, just use convolution operator where you flip the kernel both horizontally and vertically.